# Chaquopy cannot install cantools

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

I working in Android app integrated with Chaquopy. Past month [cantools](https://pypi.org/project/cantools/) working correctly. Today I am running same project I got Error: CCompiler.compile: Chaquopy cannot compile native code. I don't know why this problem occur help me to solve this problem.

```
 ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86", "x86_64"
        }

        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/way2smile/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe"

            pip{
                install "cantools"
            }

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of cantools's requirements recently released new versions with native components. You can work around this by updating your `pip` block as follows:

```
                install "cantools==39.3.0"
                install "bitstruct==8.17.0"
                install "msgpack==1.0.6"
```